# Is it possible to manipulate an ID declared in a php script with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Quick question from someone who is new to all this, thanks for any help!

If an ID is declared for an object in a php script, can I then reference and manipulate that object by referencing the ID in  separate js script?

e.g this is an excerpt from a php script which has a twitter icon in the header.

```
<div id="icons">
<a href="<?php echo TWITTER_ACCOUNT; ?>" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image6','','images/site_images/icon_t2.png',1)"><img src="images/site_images/icon_t.jpg" name="Image6" border="0" id="Image6" /></a>
 </div>
```

Can I reference the ID Image6 and then move it around in a js script?

For example by using the following in the js:

```
var bird = document.getElementById("Image6");
```

And then use that variable to reference screen position etc.

Comment: yes you can. where in the document did you place your javascript? because you would have to wait for the page to be loaded to access it

Comment: Ok cool thanks, I'll be adding the js script to the head of the php file which has the main page content. And using the document ready function so that the js only triggers when the page has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your JavaScript will work just fine. It works on the resulting HTML from the PHP page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But it will only effect the client rendering. You can modify whatever you want with JS, which is agnostic in regards to where the markup came from (php, .net, express,  etc.)